# SMS Sending from ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sms

I purchase a SMS pack. The SMS Service provider gave a link to send the SMS. this link i put it in my website, the problem is that it redirect to their website and send the SMS.

the code is 
The code in respnse.redirect url. It will redirect to services provider page they gave sample code to pass the parameter in response.redirct.

In asp.net how to resolve this link without going to their website.

Thanks
Basit.

Answer (score 0):

how about using an iframe within a hidden div? or a very small 1px iframe.
you could read the innerhtml from the frame and do something with it.

Comment: i'm adding this code from code behind becoz different sender number

Comment: Why would that stop you using an iframe - building a link in there in whatever format you need - and clicking the link using javascript from the page containing the iframe? Most 'web to sms' service providers I have come across provide a web service you can call instead of clicking a link.

Answer (score 0):

The sms sending API url come in the form of Restful service url where you can put the mobile no and the message text in the parameter and hit the Service by sending the Parameter with them, you don't need to add the Response.Redirect with the Code.